# How do I using Cheerio get the number value between a LI tat that has been populated dynamically

Tags: node.js, cheerio

How do I using Cheerio get the number in a li tag that is wrapped by UL and class tags.

I have this html snippet of the dynamic content:

```html
<ul class="numbers">
  <li class="ball winNum1">21</li>
  <li class="ball winNum2">6</li>
  <li class="ball winNum3">32</li>
  <li class="ball winNum4">14</li>
</ul>
```

```
        let $ = cheerio.load(body);
        let msg = [];
        $('li.ball').each( (i, elm)=>{

        msg[i] = $(elm).toString().trim();

      });
      console.log(msg);
```

I expect to print ['21', '6', '32', '14'] instead I get this:

```
['<li class="ball winNum1"></li>',
'<li class="ball winNum2"></li>',
'<li class="ball winNum3"></li>',
'<li class="ball winNum4"></li>']
```

and there are no numbers 21, 6, 32 or 14 in the li tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'am answering my own question after 2 days of struggle

Looks like for dynamic content cheerio may alone will not be sufficient, by using puppeteer and cheerio in combination, able to get the result I was looking for.

```
npm install puppeteer cheerio --save
```

Here is my working code after using puppeteer and cheerio

```
puppeteer
  .launch()
  .then(function(browser) {
    return browser.newPage();
  })
  .then(function(page) {
    return page.goto(url).then(function() {
      return page.content();
    });
  })
  .then(function(html) {
    $('li.ball', html).each(function() {
      console.log($(this).text());
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    //handle error
  });
```

I found "The Ultimate Guide to Web Scraping with Node.js" article very helpful to achieve my result:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-daa2027dcd3/